# Proper way to verify keycard integrity

Tags: hash

I have thought about building an electronic door locking system.

Would the following mechanism be secure at all to prevent tampering plain text information on card?

1. hash private system key together with cardholder data
2. save the hash and card holder data to an RFID card
3. the lock (which only has the private key) takes the cardholder data and hash when authenticating
4. the lock creates a hash using it's private key (the same used in creating the card) and plain text data from card.
5. Lock compares the hash it generated to hash on the card

Any particular vulnerabilities other than brute forcing?

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of your flow, but I am only getting confused. What threats do you want to secure against? What is being stored on the card? How does the lock know that the data is correct? I think that if you laid out the data flow diagram better, you might get a better sense of things.

Comment: Have you looked up how standard card authentication methods work?

Comment: "hash private system key together with cardholder data" This may be vulnerable to a [length extension attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack), depending on the hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

A hash can be copied by brief access to the smart card. This approach is basically the same as comparing strings; crypto adds no real benefit in your scenario - only obscurity, as anyone with access to *either* the private key **or** the hash will be able to authenticate. It will also be vulnerable to simple replay-attacks.

Modern RFID cards acts as [smart cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contactless_smart_card). Store a private key in the smart card, and ask the smart card to authenticate to the reader, using these keys. Smart cards are commonly set up not to hand out their key, only use it for processing.

By using proper crypto you'll essentially make a system that is secure, **as long as** there is no security problems in the smart cards, allowing copying of keys. It will typically protect against replay attacks as well, as the data the card manipulates will change for every contact.

It's also worth reading about [zero-knowledge proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof) on wikipedia. In brief, there's several methods within cryptography to prove that you know a secret, without ever revealing the secret to anyone. PKI is one obvious way; by signing you prove that you have the private key, but not the content of the private key.

Comment: It's the point you can authenticate with the hash. Maybe i wasn't clear enough, let's say the card contains a parameter which tells the reader to stop accepting the card at some date. The hash is a combination of the private key and this parameter (and the date is also in plain text separately). If the card holder does not know the private key doesn't it prevent tampering the date? I didn't find the edit button on the mobile version :)

Comment: It will still be wide open to replay attacks and cloning attacks. Using a private key in the card, and a public key in the reader also stops tampering if you sign the private key with a trusted issuer...

Comment: Nitpick: public-key crypto isn't zero-knowledge, since an attacker with unlimited resources can test all possible private keys until they find one that works with the public key. Real zero-knowledge systems are information-theoretically secure, and can't be broken even with brute-force attacks.